# Filtering dataframe rows with variable filter from a json dict

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, stock

I have a dataframe of stock prices with the stocks as columns and dates as the index. Say:

```python
pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)),columns=['stock1','stock2','stock3'],index=['2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03'])

           stock1 stock2 stock3
2023-01-01     0      1     2
2023-01-02     3      4     5
2023-01-03     6      7     8
```

I also have a json file with lists of stock names for each date:

```python
{
'2023-01-01':['stock1','stock3','stock4', 'stock5']
'2023-01-02':['stock2','stock4']
'2023-01-03':['stock1','stock2','stock3','stock5']
}
```

I need to filter this dataframe so it only contains the values of the stocks in the json at each point in time.

i.e. if on the first of jan stock 1 and 3 are in the list, but on the second only stock 2 is, then I would want the dataframe to look like this:

```python
           stock1 stock2 stock3
2023-01-01     0      NA     2
2023-01-02     NA     4      NA
2023-01-03     6      7      8
```

It is important to note that the dataframe may not contain all the elements in each list.

I have tried numerous ways to achieve this, using the `pd.mask` and `pd.where` functions for example. The only method that I have found to work is itterating over the rows with `df.T.items()`, finding the common values between df.columns and the list at each date(`set(df.columns) & set(list)`), and then applying `lambda x: pd.na if x not in list else x`. This, however, is extremely slow for large datasets and my program will have to do this operation several constantly with different dataframes and filters.

Is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the json to a dataframe and construct that dataframe to a new `stock*` based column header dataframe. Then mask the original dataframe with the existence of the column header.

```py
d = {
    '2023-01-01':['stock1','stock3','stock4', 'stock5'],
    '2023-01-02':['stock2','stock4'],
    '2023-01-03':['stock1','stock2','stock3','stock5'],
}

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').stack()
m = pd.crosstab(data.index.get_level_values(0), data).astype(bool)

out = df.where(m)
```

```
$ print(data)

2023-01-01  0    stock1
            1    stock3
            2    stock4
            3    stock5
2023-01-02  0    stock2
            1    stock4
2023-01-03  0    stock1
            1    stock2
            2    stock3
            3    stock5
dtype: object

$ print(m)

col_0       stock1  stock2  stock3  stock4  stock5
row_0
2023-01-01    True   False    True    True    True
2023-01-02   False    True   False    True   False
2023-01-03    True    True    True   False    True

$ print(out)

            stock1  stock2  stock3
2023-01-01     0.0     NaN     2.0
2023-01-02     NaN     4.0     NaN
2023-01-03     6.0     7.0     8.0
```